# how to iterate through an array value and display list object on the basis of those array values

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an array object that contains months value. I want to display these values under the "ul" tag. below is the code:

```
function LoadPrioritySlider($this, priorityObj) {
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    var monthVal = window.cebMapsApp.cebMapsViewModel.viewModel.MembershipStartMonth()
    var activeMonth = jQuery.inArray(monthVal, months);

    var temp1 = months.slice(0, activeMonth);
    var temp2 = months.slice(activeMonth, months.length)

    months = $.merge(temp2, temp1);

    $this.find(".months-bar").add(months);    
}
```

I want to display a "ul" tag and corresponding "li" tag on the basis of the array values. the "months-bar" class consists of a "ul" and also, I have added the respective months in this class**($this.find(".months-bar").add(months);)** tag and also I have added the "months". I want to display all the months as a "li" tag. how will I achieve that. Below is the code that I am working on. I know its really easy but being a beginner in jquery really makes it tough for me. sry about that.

```
<div class="months-bar">
     <ul id="demo">
          <li>A</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to have `$.each()` loop and you can create a dynamic `li` with text value of each iteration in the loop and then append it:

```js
function LoadPrioritySlider($this, priorityObj) {
  var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

  var monthVal = "Jul"; //<-----for sake of example
  var activeMonth = jQuery.inArray(monthVal, months);

  var temp1 = months.slice(0, activeMonth);
  var temp2 = months.slice(activeMonth, months.length)

  months = $.merge(temp2, temp1);

  $.each(months, function(i, v) {
    var li = $('<li>',{text:v})
    $('#demo').append(li);
  });

}
LoadPrioritySlider()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="months-bar">
  <ul id="demo">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jai. You have been of great help.